# Force lxml to resolve greater than signs to ">" instead of escaping as "&gt;"

Tags: python, lxml

I have a ton of Android xml files where I need to add prefixes to the attribute values. Given `strings.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
     <string name="someName">&lt;b>Some text&lt;/b> With some HTML formatting</string>
</resources>
```

I run my logic to add the prefix to the attribute name

```
filename = "strings.xml"
prefix = "somePrefix"
tree = etree.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
for element in root.findall("string"):
    element.attrib["name"] = f"{prefix}|{element.attrib['name']}"
etree.ElementTree(root).write(filename, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

I get

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <string name="somePrefix|someName">&lt;b&gt;Some text&lt;/b&gt; With some HTML formatting</string>
</resources>
```

I know that functionally, they're the same but as I want to reduce the noise when diffing, how would I go about getting lxml to resolve the `&gt;` to `>` in the output?

Comment: Have you considered having the canonical, checked-in copies use `&gt;`? As a reader, when I see `>` I assume it's syntactic rather than literal, so the form you currently have is something prone to double-takes.

Comment: I agree that it's weird but you know how requirements be ‍♂️

Comment: I want so hard to complain about how that `>` is not valid XML syntax, but every linter/validator I have accepts it. So instead I'm going to complain about how lenient the XML spec apparently is.